# Set selected item in Dropdown List

Tags: angular, html-select

simple question ,
how to set the selected item in dropdown list !!

in plain Html is easy https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_option_selected

but when Angular came in every thing begin to be messy !!

here is a live Demo of my question

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jrvpus?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: you can just set your `[(ngModel)]` value and it should work

Comment: Remove 2 way binding

Comment: setting ngmodule value works thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="ItemId" (change)="DoSomeThingMethods()"
                    name="itemsfromServer" required>
                <option *ngFor="let item of itemsfromServer" value="{{ item.ItemId }}" [selected]="item.ItemId == 0 ">{{ item.type }} {{ item.ItemId }}</option>
            </select>
```

now set your `[(ngModel)]` value in component.

If you set `ItemId` to `0`. 
`{ItemId : 0 ,selected : true ,type:"Type default"}` will be selected in dropdown.

Comment: sure but the site setting time limit , after 5 minutes from accepting it

Answer (score 1):

You can set it via ngModel.

Consider your template HTML;

```
<select [(ngModel)]="id" (change)="change()" name="item" required>
    <option *ngFor="let item of items" value="{{ item.id }}">
        {{ item.type }}
    </option>
</select>
```

And in you component.ts;

```
this.id = 5; //or whatever
```

Now if the items collection is like;

```
[
    {type:"t1", id:"1"},
    {type:"t2", id:"2"},
    {type:"t3", id:"3"},
    {type:"t4", id:"4"},
    {type:"t5", id:"5"},
    {type:"t6", id:"6"},
    {type:"t7", id:"7"},
]
```

Now the `type : t5` should be selected by default.